# How to customize two google maps with javascript on one page?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I need two Google maps on one page. Both of maps should have multiple pins on it. One map show hotels, another one restaurants. I tried to add pins and location names with javascript but all pins shows one location name.

**This is html code for maps:**
Hotels map:
`<div id="map-accommodation" class="interactive-map" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>`

Restaurants map:
`<div id="map-food" class="interactive-map" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>`

**This is script code for maps:**
Hotels map:

```
    var locations = [
      ['Sheraton', 41.646230, 41.649160, 1],
      ['Hilton', 41.627184, 41.5991094, 2],
      ['Radisson', 41.6296321, 41.6002718, 3]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-accommodation'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.616756, 41.636745),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
```

Restaurants map:

```
    var locations = [
      ['360 Cloud bar', 41.6472564, 41.6251435, 1],
      ['Sky bar', 41.6479619, 41.6275468, 2],
      ['Sky tower', 41.6479619, 41.6275468, 3]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-food'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.616756, 41.636745),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
```

So these maps show different locations, hotels map shows me only hotels, restaurants map shows me only restaurant pins, but all of them have one name - "sky tower".

Can you explain why and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a unique array for each map (i.e. `hotels`, `restaurants`) and if you want each map to have its own InfoWindow (both maps currently share one InfoWindow), make a unique one of those as well.

```
var hotels = [
    ['Sheraton', 41.646230, 41.649160, 1],
    ['Hilton', 41.627184, 41.5991094, 2],
    ['Radisson', 41.6296321, 41.6002718, 3]
  ];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-accommodation'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.616756, 41.636745),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < hotels.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(hotels[i][1], hotels[i][2]),
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(hotels[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
```

```
  var restaurants = [
    ['360 Cloud bar', 41.6472564, 41.6251435, 1],
    ['Sky bar', 41.6479619, 41.6275468, 2],
    ['Sky tower', 41.6479619, 41.6275468, 3]
  ];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-food'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.616756, 41.636745),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;
  for (i = 0; i < restaurants.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(restaurants[i][1], restaurants[i][2]),
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(restaurants[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/rbw9Lxfk/1/)

[image: screenshot of maps]

**code snippet:**

```js
"use strict";

// The following example creates complex markers to indicate beaches near
// Sydney, NSW, Australia. Note that the anchor is set to (0,32) to correspond
// to the base of the flagpole.
function initMap() {
  var hotels = [
    ['Sheraton', 41.646230, 41.649160, 1],
    ['Hilton', 41.627184, 41.5991094, 2],
    ['Radisson', 41.6296321, 41.6002718, 3]
  ];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-accommodation'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.616756, 41.636745),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < hotels.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(hotels[i][1], hotels[i][2]),
      map: map
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(hotels[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  var restaurants = [
    ['360 Cloud bar', 41.6472564, 41.6251435, 1],
    ['Sky bar', 41.6479619, 41.6275468, 2],
    ['Sky tower', 41.6479619, 41.6275468, 3]
  ];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-food'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.616756, 41.636745),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < restaurants.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(restaurants[i][1], restaurants[i][2]),
      map: map
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(restaurants[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Complex Marker Icons</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map-accommodation" class="interactive-map" style="width: 100%; height: 50%;"></div>
  <div id="map-food" class="interactive-map" style="width: 100%; height: 50%;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```